# Connection between background script and popup script when close the popup window

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am currently building the chrome extension named "Focus".
I am very new to chrome extension development.

But I was able to create the first version of "Focus".
It's working well in simple HTML file.
Also it's working fine when I just play around once I opened the popup window.
But when I closed the popup window, I lost all data.
I really want to keep the background process.

So I stored all the data in the background script and tried to setup the
connection between the background script and popup script.

So I used `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` and `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` to communicate between the background and popup script.

It first works. But when I closed the popup window, I can see this error.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

This is simple chrome extension.
So here I attached Github link.

https://github.com/BranchDev110/Focus-Extension

Kindly check my code and let me know the issue.
It would be great to make some PR of my repo.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The popup doesn't run when closed, so it can't receive messages. You don't need the background script here, instead just write the data to storage.